# Getting an error while starting up nginx container

Tags: nginx, dockerfile, docker-container

I'm using dockerfile to create an nginx image and it is created successfully but when I try to start the container I get below error

Error - exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory

If I use /bin/bash as an entrypoint then I can see that the /docker-entrypoint.sh is present inside the image.

```
FROM linux:8
ARG USER="oracle"
RUN useradd --create-home --home-dir /app --shell /bin/bash ${USER} && \
    dnf update -y && \
    dnf module install -y nginx:1.20 && \
    dnf clean all && \
    ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log && \
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log && \
    mkdir /var/cache/nginx && \
    chown -R ${USER}:${USER} /var/cache/nginx && \
    chmod -R 775 /var/cache/nginx && \
    chown -R ${USER}:${USER} /var/lib/nginx && \
    chown -R ${USER}:${USER} /var/log/nginx && \
    chown -R ${USER}:${USER} /etc/nginx && \
    chmod -R 775 /etc/nginx
COPY --chown=oracle:oracle conf.d /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY --chown=oracle:oracle nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY --chown=oracle:oracle docker-entrypoint.d /docker-entrypoint.d
COPY --chown=oracle:oracle docker-entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

USER ${USER}
WORKDIR /app
STOPSIGNAL SIGQUIT
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Simple test would be to check if that file has read access from your user and have the executable bit set. Permission issue is the easiest way to go down the drain quite wastefully! Keep it up and welcome home!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]` to `ENTRYPOINT ["bash",  "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]`

Comment: Or is it simply that the file doesn't have the executable bit set? I'm all for workarounds whenever it's needed but the way you answer this seems like a workaround to a completely explainable and fixable chmod +x, which eludes the whole of your answer.